# Granting root permissions to non root app

Tags: android

I have a application for editing files (for example star music tag editor) which is non root and can't grant permission to write sd card (Android 4.4 +,. Phone is rooted). Is there a way I can allow it to write "/" or "/storage/sdcard1"

Comment: I recommend using a tool like FolderMount to remount locations on the SDCard on the user volume to get around the restriction on writing. No Root needed.